# Is optimize select max(date) sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is too slow. Is it possible to optimize it?

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), MAX(dat), 101) AS MaxDate 
FROM 
    X_Prices price      
INNER JOIN 
    RMetal cat ON cat.SubCat = price.Subcat AND cat.Category = price.Category     
WHERE
    cat.Country = 'India' 
    AND cat.Section = 1 
    AND cat.active = 1 
    AND cat.inactive = 0 
    AND price.Dat < GETDATE() - 60
```

Comment: Any indices setup on the join or where columns?  Have you run `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Add an index on dat & don't use convert as this will not use index. After selecting the max date you can use sub-query and convert it to your required format.

Comment: Not a useful question without the schemas of all tables being queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), MAX(dat), 101) AS MaxDate
FROM X_Prices price INNER JOIN
     RMetal cat
     ON cat.SubCat = price.Subcat AND cat.Category = price.Category     
WHERE cat.Country = 'India' AND
      cat.Section = 1 AND
      cat.active = 1 AND
      cat.inactive = 0 AND
      price.Dat < GETDATE()- 60 ;
```

I would start with an index on `RMetal(Country, Section, Active, Inactive, Category, SubCat)` and `X_Prices(Category, SubCat, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

if u can change the DB:
replace country with country code make sure SubCat & Category are numbers, & have index (as foreign key)

if this is the DB structure u should probably add indexes based on the execution plan, probably on the entire where clause

Answer (score 0):

Apply index on

```
 Country , Section , active , inactive column of RMetal 
table And Category, SubCat, date column of X_Prices table
```